# How to get the data out of that special json?

Tags: javascript, json, django, angular, frontend

I want to make it short. I want to do a table, which contains data from a django api stream via angular. Im using the http get method from angular to do so, and it works absolutely fine with the following examples:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

While this cant be extracted. Even when i go into results with sth like

```
results: {
    id: any;
 }
```

[image]

I cant provide a link because its changing sometimes at the moment (thats not the reason why i cant parse it into my table)
Im new to Front end and programming in generally so please be precisely and comprehensive, i just want a solution and never wanna see frontend again at anytime :D.
Can there be any difference between those jsons, that i cant see or google?

I think, its pointless giving the code for the get request, because its actually working but just in case:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Tutorial } from '../models/tutorial.model';

const baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TutorialService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getAll(): Observable<Tutorial[]> {
   return this.http.get<Tutorial[]>(baseUrl);
 }
```

I really wanna get this unstructured stuff done and get back to learning java. looking at this since 20h or sth. Dark Souls is probably easy for mental health in comparison. Tell me, if u need more stuff. I cant provide information about the back end because i just have no informations aside this api, a friend of mine is taking care of it.

Comment: The semicolon inside the `results` object is a syntax error, as are the missing property values for property key `reader` further down in the post. Are these errors in the "json" you're working with?

Comment: I just whitened the Reader Values, which are Mac-Adresses and i am too greenhorn to risk to show any macs on overflow :D. Sorry for that. Do you  think, i cant read in the whole json due to this semicolon? Webstorm isnt argueing about it nor throws an error.

Comment: The comment was about syntax errors in the post. I don't actually understand what you're asking about - the link to `typicode.com` does nothing but bring up the home page, and there is no information for readers to reproduce the problem. I suggest having a read through ["how to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before updating the post, using dummy data examples and fake urls at `example.com` if you have to. And please please, please clarify what you mean by a "json" :)  Best.